# Dynamically create mergefields (Access to Word)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there anyway I can set the text of a field in Word Document using VBA from an array value?

```
Do While .Execute
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, count:=1
        Selection.Paragraphs.Indent

        For I = 0 To mergeFields.GetUpperBound(0)
            Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
            Selection.TypeText Text:="MERGEFIELD M_1"
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=2
            Selection.TypeParagraph
        Next
```

In the place of "MERGEFIELD M_1", I would like to populate that text from an array called "mergeFields", which has similarly named strings. The reason for this is because that array is dynamically set in a separate function, so I may need to create 5 new fields or up to 20 new fields.

So my idea is as followed:

```
            Selection.TypeText Text:= mergeField(I)
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=2
            Selection.TypeParagraph
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I was able to get it to work after a bit more tweaking. Here's the final code for anyone else:

```
Do While .Execute
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, count:=1
            Selection.Paragraphs.Indent

            For Each fieldName In mergeFields
                If fieldName <> "" Then
                    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
                    Selection.TypeText Text:=mergeFields(I)
                    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=2
                    Selection.TypeParagraph
                    I = I + 1
                    End If
            Next
        Loop
```